# PowerShell coding in O365

Tags: powershell, scripting

I have a question regarding sample code. I am running some scripts in O365, "Running script" as below. I want to do when a PSSession enters a "Broken" state, it will pause the script, and remove broken session (Remove-PSSession ) and re-connecting PSSession (following "Re-connecting code" as below), then restart the script. I tried to write this but but I am no familiar with coding.... Can anyone help?.....
(Server 2008 R2 SP1/PowerShell)
Any help would be appriciated.

Running Script-----

```
Import-Csv D:\work\users.csv | ForEach {
Grant-CsConferencingPolicy $_.UserPrincipalName -PolicyName BposSAllModalityNoFT}

Import-Csv D:\work\users.csv | ForEach {
Grant-CsExternalAccessPolicy $_.UserPrincipalName -PolicyName FederationOnly}
```

Re-connecting code-------

```
$sfboSession = New-CsOnlineSession -Credential $credential
Import-Pssession $sfboSession -AllowClobber
```

Answer (score 0):

`Import-csv D:\IDMaster\Tools\SkypeTool\users.txt | foreach {

```
 Do {

     Grant-CsConferencingPolicy $_.UserPrincipalName -PolicyName BposSAllModalityNoFT
```

if ($? -ne "True")
         {
             get-pssession | remove-pssession
             $sfboSession = New-CsOnlineSession -credential $credential
             Import-PSSession $sfboSession -AllowClobber  }
       } # End of 'Do'
     Until ($? -eq "True")
         Write-Host $_.UserPrincipalName "BposSAllModalityNoFT"

```
 Do {
     Grant-CsExternalAccessPolicy $_.UserPrincipalName -PolicyName FederationAndPICDefault
```

if ($? -ne "True")
         {
             get-pssession | remove-pssession
             $sfboSession = New-CsOnlineSession -credential $credential
             Import-PSSession $sfboSession -AllowClobber  }
       } # End of 'Do'
     Until ($? -eq "True")
         Write-Host $_.UserPrincipalName "FederationAndPICDefault"

```
     $string = $_.UserPrincipalName + " " + "BposSAllModalityNoFT" + " " + "FederationAndPICDefault" 
     Write-Output $string | Out-file D:\IDMaster\Tools\SkypeTool\Modify_Log.csv -Append -Encoding default
```

}`

Comment: I found soltuion myself.